# Programmatically zooming into small area of larger picture using UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to get my code to programmatically zoom into a small area of the larger picture.  I'll add the tap code later, but right now I just want to see it work.

The zoomToRect in this code does absolutely nothing and I simply don't understand why.  When I build it, the image just sits there at the 0,0 origin.

I've tried using:

setContentOffset and scrollRectToVisible and both these work fine -the image moves to the specified coordinates.  But neither of these is what I want, because I need to move and zoom the image, not just move it.

But zoomToRect utterly refuses to do anything.  I've read about 50 pages of examples and tutorials on this now and not a damn thing works.  I'm tearing my hair out not knowing why.  Clearly I'm missing some really fundamental or important point.

```
UIImage *myFirstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"manga_page.jpg"];

UIImageView *myFirstImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myFirstImage];

[myFirstImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myFirstImage.size.width, myFirstImage.size.height)];


UIScrollView *myFirstScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[myFirstScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(myFirstImage.size.width, myFirstImage.size.height)];

[myFirstScrollView addSubview:myFirstImageView];

[self.view addSubview:myFirstScrollView];

[myFirstScrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(300, 300, 300, 300) animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I did, although it might not be much use to you.  I ended up switching to the Xamarin framework (xamarin.com).

Comment: Sorry - got caught by the "can't re-edit comments after 5 mins thing" - I think from memory the problem was related to the fact that I hadn't defined the delegate for zooming - see viewForZoomingInScrollView (bottom of page) here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/viewForZoomingInScrollView:

Comment: That was exactly what my problem ended up being.  If you add that as an answer (it's totally legit to answer your own question!), I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I hadn't defined the delegate for zooming - see viewForZoomingInScrollView (bottom of page) here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/viewForZoomingInScrollView

I don't have a code fragment in Objective C as I switched to the Xamarin framework.  However the C# solution is as follows:

```
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView = delegate (UIScrollView sv) { return imageView; };
```

Where imageView is the UIImageView containing the image to be scrolled around.

Answer (score 0):

Set the maximumZoomScale and minimumZoomScale properties for the UIScrollView.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried setting both max and min ZoomScale before before posting this question here.  Seems to make no difference at all.