# How to focus specific view while zooming in scrollview Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm working in iOS App, in which I have multiple inner views in scrollview and I enabled paging in scroll view and user can also zoom scroll view can see inner views closely. All works fine but what happened there is navigation feature which highlight each inner view one by one, but in zoom I can't stay focused on each view. Inner views can be textfield, button and simple view and added in scroll view like `[scrollview addSubview:myImageView];`.

Here below is my code to navigate focus of zoomed scrollview but this is not working fine:

```
- (void)showVisibleRectInZoom:(UIView*)objectToNavigate
{
    CGFloat zoomedScaleValue =myScroll.zoomScale;

    CGPoint pointToMove = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);

    if (zoomedScaleValue > 1.0) {

        [myScroll scrollRectToVisible:objectToNavigate.frame animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Looking for help how to set scroll view visible position for each inner view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. I think this code will helpful to you:

   ```
   - (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
   self = [super initWithImage:image];
   if (self) {
       [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

       UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
       UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
       UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

       [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
       [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

       [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
       [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
       [self addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

       [singleTap release];
       [doubleTap release];
       [twoFingerTap release];
   }
   return self;
    }

   #pragma mark Private

     - (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
   if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tapDetectingImageView:gotSingleTapAtPoint:)])
       [delegate tapDetectingImageView:self gotSingleTapAtPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self]];
     }

     - (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
   if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tapDetectingImageView:gotDoubleTapAtPoint:)])
       [delegate tapDetectingImageView:self gotDoubleTapAtPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self]];
      }

      - (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
   if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tapDetectingImageView:gotTwoFingerTapAtPoint:)])
       [delegate tapDetectingImageView:self gotTwoFingerTapAtPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self]];
       }
   ```

Check more: [How to zoom into a selected area of image in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800754/how-to-zoom-into-a-selected-area-of-image-in-iphone)

2. The problem was that I hadn't defined the delegate for zooming - see viewForZoomingInScrollView (bottom of page) here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/viewForZoomingInScrollView

I don't have a code fragment in Objective C as I switched to the Xamarin framework.  However the C# solution is as follows:

```
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView = delegate (UIScrollView sv) { return imageView; };
```

Where imageView is the UIImageView containing the image to be scrolled around.

From : [Programatically zooming into small area of larger picture using UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806116/programatically-zooming-into-small-area-of-larger-picture-using-uiscrollview)